# python axhline label not showing up in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following little function:

```
def plotresults(freqs,power,prob,title,sigP):
    pl.suptitle(title)
    ax1 = pl.subplot(2,1,1)
    ax1.axhline(y=sigP, color='r', ls='--',label='p=0.05')
    pl.plot(freqs,power)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Spectral Power')

    ax2 = pl.subplot(2,1,2)
    ax2.axhline(y=0.05, color='r', ls='--', label='p=0.05')
    pl.semilogy(freqs,prob)
    ax2.set_xlabel(r'Frequency (years$^{-1}$)')
    ax2.set_ylabel('p-value')
    pl.savefig('lsfast/figs/'+title+'.png')
    pl.close()
```

It plots fine and draws the lines where they should be, but the line labels don't appear anywhere. What am I doing wrong? AN example of the output is attached:

[image: Example plot created using the above function]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The label kwarg for plot [sets the label that's used by legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label). To display it you can add a [legend](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) to your plot. Alternately, you might want to use [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) instead.

Comment: Could you please add a couple of lines of code to show how to display a legend using the label defined in axhline?

Comment: Calling `plt.legend()` displayed the label for me, however I believe you can also call that on `ax`. Ex:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;`
`plt.figure();`
`plt.axhline(y=0.5, color='r', linestyle='--', label='label');`
`plt.legend();`
`plt.show()`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think attaching a label to a line is meant to draw this label to the plot, it just associates this label with the line and can be used to create a legend.